# Write / Read data to XML or CSV and populate ListView C#

Tags: c#, xml, listview, csv

I have a problem with my student application, and I need some little help to find the best way to export data from `textboxes`,`comboboxes` and `masked textbox` to an external file.

Here is the solution that I've had tried, but it gives me wrong result.

```
namespace SistemRezervacija
{
    class IzvozPodataka
    {
        // Konstruktor
        public IzvozPodataka() { }

        // Promenljive
        private string _ime;
        private string _brojStola;
        private string _idRezervacije;
        private string _brojTelefona;
        private string _datum;
        private string _rezervacijuUneo;
        private string _napomena;

        // 
        public void exportCSV()
        {
            _frmUnosRezervacije frmUnos = new _frmUnosRezervacije();

            _ime = frmUnos._txtUnosIme.Text;
            _brojStola = frmUnos._txtUnosBrojStola.Text;
            _idRezervacije = frmUnos._txtUnosIdRezervacije.Text;
            _brojTelefona = frmUnos._txtUnosBrojTelefona.Text.ToString();
            _datum = frmUnos._dtpUnosDatum.ToString();
            _rezervacijuUneo = frmUnos._cmbUnosRezervacijuUneo.SelectedText.ToString();
            _napomena = frmUnos._txtUnosNapomena.Text;

            string putanja = @"..\..\Datoteke\Rezervacije.csv";

            if (!File.Exists(putanja))
            {
                File.Create(putanja).Close();
            }

            string delimiter = ",";
            string[][] izlaz = new string[][]
            {
                 new string [] {_ime, _brojStola.ToString(), _idRezervacije.ToString(), _brojTelefona.ToString(), _datum, _rezervacijuUneo, _napomena }
             };

            int duzina = izlaz.GetLength(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < duzina; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, izlaz[i]));
                File.AppendAllText(putanja, sb.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result of CSV export]

I need to have a CSV or XML file with column headers or xml attributes like (IME, BR. STOLA, ID REZERVACIJE, BR. TELEFONA, DATUM, REZERVACIJU UNEO, NAPOMENA) to write a each entry, and after that I need a code to read that file and populate listview in C#.

Thanks in advice

Comment: wpf/winforms ? plz choose proper tag.

Comment: The best method is to put data into a DataTable.  You can make the ListView DataSource the DataTable.  The DataTable class has a ReadXml() method and a WriteXML() method that will do everything you need.  No need to use CSV which is make all your tasks harder.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your File variable doesn't exist in the context you use it.
Some mistype is also in the line of declaration of `string[][] izlaz;`.

A simple solution is using StreamWriter, see below.

```
    using System.IO;

    //...
    public void exportCSV()
    {
        string[,] izlaz = new string[,]
        {
            { _ime, _brojStola.ToString(), _idRezervacije.ToString(), _brojTelefona.ToString(), _datum, _rezervacijuUneo, _napomena }
        };

        string putanja = @"..\..\Datoteke\Rezervacije.csv";
        string delimiter = ",";
        int duzina = izlaz.GetLength(0);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(putanja))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, izlaz[i]));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
```

I hope everything works!